# Adding default column in stored procedure result

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[fetchkey]
@carid nvarchar(50) =null
as
begin
 select t.TBarcode, t.Status 
from Transaction_tbl t 
 where t.TBarcode=@carid
end
```

my output:

```
TBarcode             Status
57173621345          3
```

I want to get a output like this:

```
TBarcode        location          Status
-----------------------------------------
57173621345     deliverd         3
```

I need the location column  to show always deliverd only. 
So how I can do this?. Do I need to use a function or is there any simple way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the select in the SP to something like

```
select  t.TBarcode, 
        'delivered' location,
        t.Status 
from    Transaction_tbl t 
where   t.TBarcode=@carid
```

From [SELECT Clause (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176104.aspx)

You can see that the syntax is as follows

```
SELECT [ ALL | DISTINCT ]
[ TOP ( expression ) [ PERCENT ] [ WITH TIES ] ] 
<select_list> 
<select_list> ::= 
    { 
      * 
      | { table_name | view_name | table_alias }.* 
      | {
          [ { table_name | view_name | table_alias }. ]
               { column_name | $IDENTITY | $ROWGUID } 
          | udt_column_name [ { . | :: } { { property_name | field_name } 
            | method_name ( argument [ ,...n] ) } ]
          | expression
          [ [ AS ] column_alias ] 
         }
      | column_alias = expression 
    } [ ,...n ]
```

Where expression in the above is defined as

> Is a constant, function, any combination of column names, constants,
>   and functions connected by an operator or operators, or a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[fetchkey] 

@carid NVARCHAR(50) = NULL

AS BEGIN

     SELECT
           t.TBarcode
         , Location = 'delivered' 
         , t.[status]
     FROM dbo.Transaction_tbl t
     WHERE t.TBarcode = ISNULL(@carid, T.TBarcode)

END
```